# How to use the non-minified dev environment in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a webapp created using ReactJS in production. After adding a new feature, I am getting the following error `Error: Minified React error #130; visit http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=130&args[]=undefined&args[]= for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings`

When I click the link, this is the summarized error message:
`Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.`

This feature works on the local instance, it is when I deploy on the server, the error pops up.

I did not create this project from scratch, I took over from someone else. In the project root, there is a file called `.env.development` (on my local instance) whereas the codebase on the server has a file called `.env`

I am not sure if this is of any significance, just wanted give out all the details.

In order to create the production build, I used the following command `sudo npm run build`

This are my build scripts in `package.json`:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired --max_old_space_size=8192 build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

This is the `config-overrides.js`

```
module.exports = function override(config, env) {
  if (env === 'production') {
    config.devtool = false;
  }
  return config;
};
```

I want to know how to get the full error which would make the error easier to debug.